# realm java: Mmap() failed: Out of memory size

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, realm-java

io.realm.exceptions.RealmError: Unrecoverable error. mmap() failed: Out of memory size: 1073741824

```
offset: 0 in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java-release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsSharedRealm.cpp line 101
at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.nativeGetSharedRealm(Native Method)
at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.(OsSharedRealm.java:171)
at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.getInstance(OsSharedRealm.java:241)
at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.getInstance(OsSharedRealm.java:231)
at io.realm.RealmCache.doCreateRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:332)
at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:285)
at io.realm.Realm.getDefaultInstance(Realm.java:407)

minSdkVersion 22
targetSdkVersion 28
classpath “io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:6.0.0”
```

a database of 1GB, even can’t delete data because you get this error.
Please help to solve the problem :(

I have many places I read about this problem, basically there was a transaction, but I have an error voznikaet immediately after initialisatie, that is, no other transaction no.

Comment: You may need to call `compactOnLaunch()` or its overloaded method, while constructing `RealmConfiguration` object.

Comment: @VasanthJegathesan I tried to do so, immediately after initialization, but paluay the same mistake.